# Why am I getting an Invalid left-hand side in postfix expression on this line of code below?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting an invalid left-hand side in postfix expression error for this line of code

```
data: 'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID='+<?php echo $bidItemID ;?>+'',
```

I'm trying to perform an ajax call

```
function AutoRefresh(){
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "AjaxCall.php",
data: 'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID='+<?php echo $bidItemID ;?>+'',
cache: false,
success: function(data){
var autions = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
if(autions.aution_max>0){
$("#CurrentBid").html(formatCurrency(parseFloat(autions.aution_max).toFixed(2)));
}
else {
$("#CurrentBid").html(formatCurrency(parseFloat(autions.aution_max).toFixed(2)));  
}
$(".CurrentBidTop").html(formatCurrency(parseFloat(autions.aution_max).toFixed(2)));
// $(".CurrentBidTop2").html(formatCurrency(parseFloat(autions.aution_max).toFixed(2)));
$("#bidIncrement").html(autions.bid_Increment);
$("#bidAmountCount").html(autions.auction_count);

var bidAmountEnter = $('#bidAmountEnter').attr('placeholder');
// var bidIncrement=autions.bid_Increment;
//alert(parseFloat(autions.aution_max)+parseFloat(autions.bid_Increment));
var          bidIncrementFinal=parseFloat(parseFloat(autions.aution_max)+parseFloat(autions.bid_Increment)).toFi  xed(2);
var currentProxyBid='<?php echo $proxyCid[0]["proxyamount"];?>';
var ItemMaxBid='<?php echo $proxyOid[0]['proxyamount'];?>';
//console.log(autions.proxybid);
//console.log(currentProxyBid);
if(ItemMaxBid < parseFloat(autions.proxybid))
{
 location.reload(true);
//console.log("inside");
//$("#proxyBid").html(autions.proxybid);
}else{
//console.log("empty");
//$("#proxybidd").html('');
}

var CurrentBid='<?php echo $bidcurrent;?>';
console.log(parseFloat(CurrentBid));
console.log(parseFloat(autions.aution_max));
if(parseFloat(CurrentBid) < parseFloat(autions.aution_max)){

$("#bidAmountEnter").attr("placeholder",     formatCurrency(parseFloat(bidIncrementFinal).toFixed(2)));
location.reload(true);
 /* $("#bidAmountEnter").val('$'+formatCurrency(parseFloat(bidIncrementFinal).toFixed(2))); */
}


}
```

});
}

Comment: Is JavaScript giving you that error, or is PHP giving you that error?  If it's JavaScript, in the page source what was the resulting JavaScript code for that line?

Comment: BTW the `+''` seem to be redundant at the end of the line. There's no purpose to concatenating an empty string onto another string, because it adds, unsurprisingly, _nothing_ onto the end!

Comment: For that matter, there's no point in any concatenation at all, since the `<?php ___?>` part happens server-side. So: `data: 'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID=<?php echo $bidItemID ;?>',` should be sufficient, presumably outputting JavaScript code for a property like this:`data: 'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID=123',`.

Comment: The info is a little vague and lacks any obvious attempt to debug it or dig deeper, but I'm going to guess that `<?php echo $bidItemID ;?>` didn't in fact echo anything, and therefore you've ended up with `data: 'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID='++''` as the final rendered string in the JavaScript, which of course makes no sense because you can't increment a string. And as the comment above notes as well, you didn't actually need the `+`s in the first place - you could have just had PHP dump that value directly into the string, since PHP runs first on the server in order to build the JS

Comment: I don't know this is advanced level stuff here probably not for a 2 year associates degree, lol

Comment: Which bit do you think is advanced? I wouldn't really regard a simple check to see what your php had actually output as being advanced, for example

Answer (score 1):

That's the error message that Chrome throws with this code:

```js
'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID='++''
```

Firefox throws a maybe more informative:

> SyntaxError: invalid increment/decrement operand

This happens when `$bidItemID` contains something that, when cast to string, becomes an empty string.

```
data: 'Action=AutionMaxBid&AuctionItemID='+<?php echo $bidItemID ;?>+'',
```

Don't forget the PHP is a server-side language, so it runs before JavaScript (and in a different computer). The browser does not get to see PHP code, it just sees the *generated* JavaScript code.